# ajax calls return php array, json doesnt seem correct

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have an ajax call that fires a php script that returns an array.

the php:

```
 $errors[1] = "you didn't enter name"; 
 $errors[2] = "your email is incorrect";
 $errors[3] = "You didnt enter password";
 echo json_encode($errors);
```

the javascript:

```
 .....
 datatype:'json',
 success: function(result)
 {
 alert(result);   
 }
```

I would expect to see:

```
 {"1":"you didn't enter name","2":"your email is incorrect","3":"You didnt enter password"}
```

instead i see:
     ["you didn't enter name","your email is incorrect","You didnt enter password]

it seems like the json_encode did something funky.  what am i missing

Comment: Because what you wanted was `$errors['1']` and what you have is `$errors[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo json_encode($errors, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Also, yout PHP script should contain:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

before any `echo` statements.

Comment: thanks @wroniasty, this seemed to help.  how i have:<br/>
<br/>
 {"0":"you didn't enter name","1":"your email is incorrect","2":"You didnt enter password"}<br/>
<br>
if i try to ititerate through it: for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)<br>
when i print array[i]<br>
(array[0] = {<br>
array[1] = "<br>
array[2] = 0<br>
  i get each individual character,  not what is in "0"....make sense?<br>

Comment: To iterate over an `Object` use: `for (var key in obj) { var element = obj[key]; console.log(element); }`

Comment: I know i am noobing this all up.   i get same result with the for loop.  the console log shows { then " then 0 then " and so on...its almost like the javascript doesnt see it as an array but a long string.

Comment: Perhaps it IS a string, what does `console.log(typeof result)` output?

Comment: string....if i alert(result) i get this  {"0":"firstName must contain a value.",  "1":"lastName must contain a value.",  "2":"callIdfirstName must contain a value.",  "3":"callIdlastName must contain a value.",  "4":"street must contain a value.",  "5":"city must contain a value."}
my code on the php page. echo json_encode($errors, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);  
I even tried  php::json_last_error() and got a 0.

Comment: my php array:Array
(
    [0] => firstName must contain a value.
    [1] => lastName must contain a value.
    [2] => callIdfirstName must contain a value.
    [3] => callIdlastName must contain a value.
    [4] => street must contain a value.
    [5] => city must contain a value.
)

Comment: got it.  header("Content-Type: application/json");
was the answer.  thank you a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just used numbers as keys, it assumed you wanted an Array.

Answer (score 1):

Then setting this wrong, because that way will fail, by undefined vars.

```
$errors[1] = "you didn't enter name"; 
$errors[2] = "your email is incorrect";
$errors[3] = "You didnt enter password";
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Don't use this array configuration, instead use:

```
$errors=array(NULL,
  "you didn't enter name",
  "your email is incorrect",
  "You didnt enter password"
);
echo json_encode($errors, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```